# render a qt overlay window over opengl child window

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl, dwm

I am looking for some information about rendering child windows in specific about how OpenGL interop with GDI. The problem that I have is that I have basically is that I have two windows, first, the main windows are created in qt, and inside of qt, a child window is hosted that leverages an OpenGL renderer.

Now what I wanted to do is to host an overlay on top of my OpenGL window, so I use that to overlay the OpenGL window. The problem that I am having is that when I render with OpenGL, the OpenGL generated graphics seem to obscure the graphics area including and effectively undo the graphics composited by qt.

In the image below the blue area is the qt overlay, in that picture I'm using GDI (BeginPaint/EndPaint) so and the windows seem to interact fine. That is, window order seems correct, the client region is correct. The moment I start to render with Opengl the blue area gets replaced with whatever OpenGL renders.

What I did I basically created to create the overlay I created a second frameless, topmost `QMainWindow`, and once the platform HWND was initialized I reparent it. Basically I change the new windows parent to be the same parent of my OpenGL window.

What I believed this would do is that the every window, gets drawn separately and the desktop composition manager would make the final composition and basically avoiding the infamous [airspace](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/152) problem as documented by Microsoft in their WPF framework.

---

What I would like to know is what could cause these issues? At this point, I lack understanding why once i render with OpenGL the pixels by qt overlay are obscured, even though windows hierarchy should say make them composited. What could I do to accomplish what I want?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mixing OpenGL and GDI drawing on a shared drawable (that also includes sibling / childwindows without the `CS_OWNDC` windowclass style flag) ***never*** was supported. That's not something about Qt, but simply how OpenGL and GDI interact.

But the more important issue is: *Why the hell aren't you using the OpenGL support built right into Qt in the first place?* Ever since Qt-5 – if available – uses OpenGL to draw everything (all the UI elements). Qt-5 makes it trivial to mix Qt stuff and OpenGL drawing.

Comment: My OpenGL window has `CS_OWNDC ` set, I assume the windows from Qt as you said qt uses OpenGL as a backend, also has CS_OWNDC set. Regarding why i don't use the opengl context from qt- is because simply said, the renderer is not even in the same process.

Comment: @LawrenceKok, ah, that makes a lot more sense then. Well, IPC OpenGL can be done, but it's kind of annoying to set up correctly. Would it be possible for your renderer process to render-to-texture on a FBO? If so, you could use Vulkan to create the texture, export the texture to the GUI process and on either side import the texture to OpenGL to render to and composite to the GUI.

Comment: Technically, yes I can render off-screen, but yeah it might be too big of an overhaul in architechture, ideally I would rather not do it, unless there's really no other choice. 

What i don't really understand in this story, when I have a opengl context running in a (floating/moveable) window, it can be partially occluded by another window. What I mean my opengl renderer can be occluded by a browser say firefox, and the DWM is able to handle that just fine. It really makes me wonder why this case is so special, because ultimately, qt/opengl renderer is completely sandboxed.